# wp_get_attachment_metadata()['image_meta'] fetch WP metadata or EXIF?

Tags: post-thumbnails, post-meta

`wp_get_attachment_metadata( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) )['image_meta']['credit']` returns nothing although there IS information in the attachment's credit field.

Is `wp_get_attachment_metadata` for that EXIF data stuff or is it for the fields in the media manager?

Am I stupid?

Answer (score 0):

It is for EXIF data.

But if that's the code you're using, it looks like you are trying to access array elements on a function call.

Try

```
$my_data = wp_get_attachment_metadata( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );

echo $my_data['image_meta']['credit'];
```